# Input type time 'manual entry' as default

Tags: html, input, time, clock, android-timepicker

I'm running into a problem regarding the default type=time timepicker on Android devices.

```html
<div class="bw-input">
  <label>Hours</label>
  <input type="time" v-model="hours" step="900">
</div>
```

I would like to preselect the default (old-school) keyboard (date time picker) instead of the clock timepicker.
Does anybody knows how to achieve this?

Current default time picker on Android device

[image: Clock time picker screenshot]

Preferred default time picker for Android devices
[image: Preferred time picker]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that `type="time"` is implemented may vary depending on the browser you use. You have limited control in the way that controls are displayed.
If you want more control and have a more universal user experience across different platforms/browsers, best way is to use a third party time picker component.